# can i attach arrow with the tooltip in d3?

Tags: d3.js

I have my chart fiddle here. I want to make tooltip with an arrow. Can i do that in d3?[attached fiddle of graph](https://jsfiddle.net/c74eoo2b/11/)

css for the tooltip for now-

```
.hor_tooltip {
position: absolute;
width: 50px;
height: auto;
padding: 10px;
background-color: white;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
-moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
pointer-events: none;
display:none
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add

```
.hor_tooltip:after {
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-left-color: #ffffff;
  border-width: 10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/c74eoo2b/12/